# Ford Fiesta Mk6 Diesel Engine Fault

Tags: engine, electrical, ford, fuel-system, fiesta

Upon acceleration the following lights illuminate once the engine reaches 3000-4000 RPM:

[image: Engine Lights]

A message; "Engine Fault" appears on the dash screen. Once this happens, the engine will no longer rev beyond the 3000-4000 RPM range.

On a few occasions this has also resulted in a steering assist fault, where the power steering cuts out, and usually this also causes the engine to idle, and will not rev at all.

I have the following Ford Fiesta Model

[image: Ford Fiesta Mk6 Diesel]

Various mechanics have looked into this issue and all come up with different theories on what might be causing the problem:

- Faulty mass airflow sensor (this was replaced - no solution to faults)
- Faulty alternator
- Faulty ECU
- Faulty fuel pump

Does anyone have any experience of this issue, and what might be causing it?

Comment: In this case only a diagnostic interface can tell what's wrong (the car of course won't display the error code on the dashboard itself - that would be too easy), so go to the dealership or buy a good counterfeit of the diag interface (as the official one isn't for sale obviously).

Comment: I agree with the comment to get the codes read. With the codes it's going to be far easier to help you with your issue.

Comment: Agreed.  You can get a reader for about $15 on Amazon.  Some repair shops do diagnostics for free.  So does AutoZone.

Comment: Did you get this resolved? Can you give us an update?

Comment: Flagging as too broad since OP isn't responding to comments.